# Why do I get wrong conversion from hex to decimal with strtoul function in Visual Studio compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, long-integer, strtol, strtoull

I am converting a string from hex to decimal. The problem is that in Visual Studio compiler the conversion returns a wrong value. However when I compile the same code in a Mac at the terminal using the g++ compiler, the value is returned correctly.

Why this is happening?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string hex = "412ce69800";

    unsigned long n = strtoul( hex.c_str(), nullptr, 16 ); 

    cout<<"The value to convert is: "<<hex<<" hex\n\n";
    cout<<"The converted value is: "<<n<<" dec\n\n";
    cout<<"The converted value should be: "<<"279926183936 dec\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

output:

[image: output file]

Comment: Note that VS is an IDE, **not** compiler. It uses MS's `cl.exe`compiler internally and you can also run `cl` from command line just like gcc

Answer (score 2):

Because in Windows **`long` is a 32-bit type**, unlike most Unix/Linux implementations which use [LP64 memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) in which `long` is 64 bits. The number `412ce69800` has 39 bits and inherently it can't be stored in a 32-bit type. **Read compiler warnings** and you'll know the issue immediately

C standard only requires `long` to have at least 32 bits. C99 added a new `long long` type with at least 64 bits, and that's guaranteed in all platforms. So if your value is in 64-bit type's range, use `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t/uint_least64_t` and [`strtoull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtoull-strtoull-l-wcstoull-wcstoull-l?view=vs-2017) instead to get the correct value.

Comment: I think it's compiler-dependent, not OS-dependent. In addition, I'm not sure that you're solution will work, since `strtoul` returns `unsigned long` in any case.

Comment: @barakmanos I've edited to use strtoull several minutes ago, and all compilers I've known conform to the OS's type

Comment: I've had the chance to work on embedded SW which was running "standalone" (i.e., no OS, no scheduling, no virtual memory, processes, threads, etc). So I can't see how the size of types there was determined by anything else other than the compiler. If anything, the compiler would conform to the CPU architecture.

Comment: @barakmanos of course the type is defined by the compiler. Maybe there are some weird compilers that have 18-bit int or 16-bit char on x86 but still fully conform to C standard, but I've never known such one like that. All the one I've known have the type size the same as the OS they target (if any), if there's no OS then they can have the size they want

Comment: I admit I haven't fully investigated this, but intuitively, I would guess that **the OS itself**, which is designated to run over a specific processor, is built using the appropriate tool-chain (i.e., compiler and linker suitable for the specific processor at hand). So the correct way to look at it would be that type-size is determined by the compiler. Again, that's just what my intuition tells me.

Comment: @barakmanos I don't mean your statement is wrong. Inherently the size depends on compiler. But most compilers target a specific OS uses the same type size like other compilers on that platform. For example although gcc has roots from Unix, when targetting Windows it also uses 32-bit long like any other Windows compiler for conformation, and when targetting 16 or 8-bit microcontrollers it uses 16-bit int. That's the OP's problem because different sizes cause the number to overflow on Windows